# How to run multiple screens each with a command programmatically?

Tags: linux, shell, gnu-screen

I'm new to linux screen utility, and now I have to create a lot of screens, passing each some command. How to achieve that programmatically instead of creating each screen with (Ctrl+a c) and typing the command there?

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: because I 'm parallelizing some process on multi core machine, so each screen will run a command with specific parameter that is changed with each screen.

Comment: Why not use `nohup` or just run your jobs in the background with `&` ?

Answer (score 0):

Use `tmux` instead, `tmux` has a more modern API and is easy to use in most cases. To achieve you purpose with `tmux`, you need:

```
$ tmux new-session -s foo -d                # create a new session called foo
$ tmux new-window -t foo                    # create a new window
$ tmux send-keys -t foo.0 ./your_script.sh  # window number starts with 0
$ tmux new-window -t foo                    # another new window
$ tmux send-keys -t foo.1 ./another_command # another of your script
...
$ tmux attach -t foo                        # attach to your session, escape key is ^b
```